# My omnett++ simulation is stuck in a loop

Tags: omnet++

Whenever I run my simulation the msg that is initial created at rdrchk1 gets stuck going between
rdrchk1 and rdrsucess1.
Here is my C++ code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;


class rdr : public cSimpleModule
{
  protected:
    // The following redefined virtual function holds the algorithm.
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;


};

// The module class needs to be registered with OMNeT++
Define_Module(rdr);

void rdr::initialize()
{
    int v1 = rand() % 100;
        int v2 = rand() % 100;
        int v3 = rand() % 100;
    if (strcmp("rdrchk1", getName()) == 0) {

        cMessage *msg = new cMessage("objectcheck");


     if (v1<78|| v2 < 82 || v3 <69){
         int n = 0;
         send(msg, "out", n);
     }
     else{
         int d=1;
                  send(msg, "out", d);

     }
    }

}

void rdr::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{

    int t = 0;
    send(msg, "out",t);


}
```

Here is my NED code:

```
simple rdr
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=block/routing");
    gates:
        input in[4];
        output out[4];
}

//

network radr
{
    @display("bgb=356,232");
    submodules:
        rdrchk1: rdr {
            @display("p=85,67");
        }
        rdrfail1: rdr {
            @display("p=275,133;i=block/wheelbarrow");
        }
        rdrsucess1: rdr {
            @display("p=291,61");
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
        
        rdrchk1.out[1] --> rdrfail1.in++;
        rdrchk1.out[0] --> rdrsucess1.in++;
        rdrchk1.in[2] <-- rdrfail1.out++;
        rdrchk1.in[3] <-- rdrsucess1.out++;
                




}
```

I know it's stuck because whenever I edit my code so that it is guaranteed  to go to rdrfail1 the next step it is stuck going between rdrchk1 and rdrsucess1. Can any one tell me why it is doing that and what I could do to fix it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what is happening in your model.

1. In `initialize()` of `rdrchk1` a new message is created. Then that message is sent:
   a. to `rdrsucess1` when the condition `if (v1<78|| v2 < 82 || v3 <69)` is true
   *or*
   b. to `rdrfail1` otherwise
2. If `rdrsucess1` receives the message, it immediately sends that message to `rdrchk1` (because in your network port with index 0 of gate `out` of `rdrsucess1` is connected to `rdrchk1`).
3. If `rdrfail1` receives the message, it immediately sends that message to `rdrchk1` (because in your network port with index 0 of gate `out` of `rdrfail1` is connected to `rdrchk1`).
4. Then `rdrchk1` receives the message and sends it immediately to `rdrsucess1`.

Then points 2 and 4 are repeated endlessly.